# Given $n$ not prime, is there always a $1<k<n$, such that $n \nmid \binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My kid shared something from internet on Pascal's triangle that, if $p$ is a prime, then for the $p$-th row, except the beginning and ending $1$, each number is divisible by $p$. This is, of course, true, as $p \space | \binom{p}{k}$, for $1<k<p$.

Then he posted a question, seems if $n$ is not a prime, there's always a $k$, $1<k<n$, such that $n \nmid \binom{n}{k}$. I searched for Pascal's triangles on the web, this looks true, but is it always true, or I just didn't look at a Pascal's triangle big enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $n$, and let $e$ be the largest integer such $p^e \mid n$ (we denote this with $p^e \mid \mid n$).

Then $p^{e-1} \mid \mid {n \choose p}=\frac{n (n-1) \cdots (n-(p-1))}{p (p-1) \cdots 1}$, and therefore $n \nmid {n \choose p}$.